# A problem on linear transformation in finite dimensional vector spaces .

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let, $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb F$ . Determine all possible linear maps $T : V \to V$ such that  $T^k = T$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$ .

$\mathbf {My \ approach} :$ Obviously, if $V$ is finite dimensional, then for $T^2=T$ ; for any vector $x \in V$ , $x= (T(x)) + (x - T(x))$ and so $V= \mathcal F \oplus Ker T$ where $\mathcal F = \{ y \in V \ | \ T(y)=y \}$ .
 In other words, $T$ represents all possible projection mappings of the subspace $\mathcal F$ along $Ker T$ .

Now, my question is can we always find some idempotent matrix in the sequence of degrees of $T$ when given $T^k =T$ ???

And what happens if $V$ becomes infinite dimensional ???

In the above two cases, is there any relation between $T$ and projection of a subspace along another subspace ???

Comment: $T$ need not be idempotent. For example take a rotation matrix by (say) angle $\frac{\pi}{3}$, then $T^6=I \implies T^7=T$ but $T^k \neq T$ for $1<k<7$.

Comment: @Anurag A, Sir, I was thinking if it could have been possible to use the case for $k=2$ , which gives us an idempotent .

Comment: @ Rabi Kumar I am not sure if I understand the intent of your comment. If you specify, $k=2$, then of course you are referring to idempotent transformation which by definition are projections. But your problem says $T^k=T$ for **some** $k \in \Bbb{N}$, this means $k$ need not be $2$ and that's what my example refers to.

Comment: Sir, I mentioned to find an idempotent matrix in the sequence of degrees of $T$, not referring $T$ to be an idempotent .